# How can I determine which package is adding .emacs.d to my load-path?

Tags: elisp, debugging, config

I have a bunch of packages installed. 
One of them is adding `~/.emacs.d` to my `load-path`, which Emacs is (unsurprisingly) complaining about.

I could be incorrect here, but:

Attempting to bisect my set of packages is a slow work, because I'd have to uninstall all my packages, and then re-install only half of them, which means downloading, and a lot of fairly manual work.

Is there an easier way to determine which package is setting the value of `load-path`?

Extra information:

- This doesn't happen when loading emacs with `-Q`.
- I've not changed my config between it working and breaking, only upgrade packages
- <s>This *doesn't* happen if I run `emacs` without a site-file (`--no-site-file`), regardless of whether I add `--no-site-lisp`</s> I confused my flags here.
- This *doesn't* happen if run `emacs` with `--no-init-file`. `site-file` / `site-lisp` have no effect
- GNU Emacs 24.4.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2015-03-31
- `Bug Hunter` tells me that **`package-initialise`** is to blame
- `grep -aR "'load-path" ~/.emac.d/elpa --include '*el' | egrep -v ':[[:space:]]*;+' | fgrep -v "(add-to-list 'load-path (or (file-name-directory #$) (car load-path)))"` gives no results
- **Removing all my** `.elc` **files in** `~/.emacs.d/elpa` **appeared to fix this problem**, although it's not a great solution. I'm not going to submit & accept because I've no idea how works or whether it's really a fix. This is easily done with `find ~/.emacs.d/elpa -name '*.elc' -delete`

Comment: It's very surprising if any package is doing that. I wouldn't think they have any business adding anything outside of their own `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` sub-directories to the `load-path`. Could you at least confirm to us that it's not your init file (or any other start-up library), by commenting out all of its contents and then running `emacs --no-site-file --no-site-lisp` and checking the value of `load-path`? (Offhand I'm not sure whether using `emacs -q` inhibits elpa packages or not.)

Comment: Another suggestion: If this behavior started only recently, try to remember what packages you last added to your setup (checking timestamps of packages in your `elpa` directory should help), and what parts of your init-file you recently changed. If you are using a version control system to keep track of changes to your config, this is trivial -- all you need to do is have a look at the most recent commits.

Comment: I have the same problem; please post the actual answer (not just the grep/bisect suggestions) when you find it!

Comment: Could you explain what makes you think it comes from a package, and what do you mean by such a package (do you mean an ELPA package, or just an Elisp package installed by hand)?

Comment: (1) Try grepping for `load-path` without the quote, there are plenty of ways to modify a variable without quoting the name. (2) If that doesn't work, also try grepping the `elc` files. Grep will think they're binary files, but it'll still tell you which ones match. (3) In case you end up having to check packages one-by-one: I grepped my elpa and both `python-mode` and `w3m` made suspicious use of the load-path. I'm not saying they're wrong, I'm just saying I would start with them.

Comment: removing and recompiling elpa/*/*.elc files did not help me

Comment: To both MrBones and @sds: Do you, by any chance, have a file in your `.emacs.d` directory whose name ends with `-pkg.el`? If so, that could be the cause.

Comment: @Malabarba: yes, all my packages are in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` - but `ls` reports: `ls: /Users/sds/.emacs.d/*-pkg.el: No such file or directory`

Comment: @sds Nevermind then, that's not the problem. It would only be a problem if there were a `-pkg` file directly inside `.emacs.d`.

Comment: I just noticed that my warning is caused by presence of `"."` in `load-paths`; it is there together with the standard Emacs/lisp source tree directories: ` "./vc" "./url" "./textmodes" "./progmodes" ...`. Do you have any relative paths in your `load-path`?

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches come to mind.

#### Use `rgrep`

... to search for offending code:

1. Open your `elpa` directory in Dired. If you're not sure where this directory is located, check the value of `package-user-dir` with <kbd>C-h v</kbd>.
2. Call `rgrep`:

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> `add-to-list 'loadpath` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*.el` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

   You might need to play around with the exact search string a bit to narrow down the list of results.

#### Use `package-load-list`

... to control which packages are loaded:

1. Check the value of `package-activated-list` to get a list of packages that are currently activated.
2. Add the following code to your init-file:

   ```el
   (setq package-load-list '((magit nil) (multiple-cursors nil) ...))
   ```

   Replace `(magit nil) (multiple-cursors nil) ...` with about half of the packages that are currently activated. (Note that `nil` means "load the latest version" in this context.) Emacs will load all packages that you list at startup and ignore the remaining packages.
3. Restart Emacs to see if the error persists. If it does, keep bisecting the list of packages you are loading until you are left with the package that is causing the problem.

Comment: Hmm, this is happening even when I comment out my entire init.el. It also happens when I set my package-load-list to nil

Comment: @MrBones A couple more ideas: 1. What is the value of `user-init-file`? Make sure it points to the correct file. 2. What happens when you start Emacs via `emacs -Q`? 3. What is the exact error/warning message you are getting?

Comment: 1.) User init is correct 2) Nothing interesting happens with -Q. I get a vanilla emacs. 3) `Your 'load-path' seems to contain your '.emacs.d' directory: ...` and if I inspect-variable on load-path, sure enough my .emacs.d is in there

Comment: @MrBones What happens when you do `M-x` `package-initialize` `RET` right after starting Emacs via `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Nothing. No packages are loaded

Comment: @MrBones "No packages are loaded" -- How did you determine that that's the case? If there are no errors during package initialization, Emacs will keep quiet; it won't output any messages to the `*Messages*` buffer. To verify that package initialization worked, try calling a command from a third-party package after doing `M-x` `package-initialize`.

Comment: Ah, I tried some keybinds for 3rd-party packages, forgetting that they're non-standard bindings. They do in fact get loaded correctly, without warning

Comment: @MrBones I'm running out of ideas. If I were you I'd probably proceed by running `rgrep` from the `elpa` dir (and possibly also from the directories listed in `package-directory-list`), paying special attention to packages that were recently updated when examining the results. If that doesn't turn up anything useful, bisecting my init-file would be my next step.

Answer (score 3):

The [Bug-Hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter) may be able to help you with that.

1. Install the `bug-hunter` package from the Package-Menu.
2. Invoke `M-x bug-hunter-init-file`
3. It will ask you for an assertion, type (or paste) in the following predicate and hit `RET`.

   ```
   (or (member "~/.emacs.d/" load-path)
       (member (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/") load-path))
   ```

That's it! You'll be presented with a buffer reporting the results, similar to this one:
[image: cl]
*(this run was testing which package was doing a `(require 'cl)`)*

#### Things to consider

The bug-hunter can only analyse your init file, so if the problem is
happening during autoloading time, then it's only going to blame
`(package-initialize)` (which is not very useful).

On the other hand, if it happens during package `require` time, if
it's something else in your init file, or if it's something in the
site-files, the Bug-Hunter should give some relevant information.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's happening during `(package-initialize)`, but nice tool

Comment: @MrBones shame :-(. Then it's probably an autoload file in your Elpa subdir.

Comment: This feels like a bug. If I start emacs with a commented out config from inside my .emacs.d folder I get the error message. If I start emacs in my .emacs.d folder with -q I don't get the error.

Comment: @JordonBiondo If you comment out your configs then installed packages will still be initialized. If you start with `-q` they won't. That means this is being caused by a package autoload.

Comment: regardless of whether package-initialize is called?

Comment: @JordonBiondo Yes. `package-initialize` simply lets you do the initialization ahead of time. They'll be initialized anyway after your init file is finished loading, even if the init file was empty.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
(setq load-path (cl-delete-if-not #'file-name-absolute-p load-path))
```

to my `.emacs.el` fixed this problem for me.

The problem manifests itself unless I pass the [`--no-site-lisp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html) option.

I filed a [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21104).